# How to Decrypt using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a  captcha text,which I am storing in hidden variable and retreiving the value in code behind(c#.net).

Now I need to Encrypt that captcha text and store in hidden variable and decrypt the same in c#.net

I need an algorithm that works both in javascript and c# .i.e encrypt in javascript and decrypt in c#.net.

eg : text : "dfg563hj"

Thanks for your help in advance.
Ramesh.

Comment: Its would be waist if javascript was able to encrypt/decrypt the value. Anyone would be able to view the javascript and see what key/algorithm you are using to do the "encryption".

Comment: encrypting & decrypting in JavaScript will expose the encryption codes to public. People can decrypt it using your codes. It is suggested to put all encryption codes in server side.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, @Shivan: You can encrypt with a public key, and decrypt with a private key. This is the basis of [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy), for instance. So it does not necessarily expose anything *private* to be doing the public part on the client browser. You gain en route tamper detection, but @user note that you gain *nothing* in terms of intentionally-spoofed messages reaching your server.

Comment: Does the PO want the entered text to be encrypted, or want to have the captcha text itself on client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also do not think this is a good idea because they'd be able to see how to do the decryption..
Here's javascript for doing a DES decryption
http://www.teslacore.it/sssup1/des.js

you just need to call

```
encryptedText = des(password, unHex(contents), 0);
```

Here's c# for doing DES encyption

```
public static string Encrypt(string originalString)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(originalString))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException
               ("The string which needs to be encrypted can not be null.");
    } 
    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, 
        cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(bytes, bytes), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
    writer.Write(originalString);
    writer.Flush();
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    writer.Flush();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
}
```

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Whether such an encryption exists or not, it would be a bad idea to have Captcha text in Client side and modified using JavaScript.